# Make a clean NSString of words from a NSMutableArray of word objects, then use for search

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

**suitsArray** is MutableArray with objects (words) added when buttons are in selected state.

In the following piece, I need to make **suitsCriteriaString** a *clean string with only a space separating the words from* **suitsArray**, meaning no comma or other symbols! (with NSSet or something?)

```
NSString *suitsCriteriaString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", suitsArray];
NSString *wineSuitsString = [wine objectForKey:@"Suits"];
NSRange range = [wineSuitsString rangeOfString:suitsCriteriaString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Then, the **NSRange**, if it's done right, should check if the **words in suitsCriteriaString**, are existing in **wineSuitsString**. Then, the results should be filtered to containing only the matching words!

Codes for my search function follows, let me know if you need some more info to make this work.

---

**SearchViewController.h**

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController {

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allObjectsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *resultObjectsArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *suitsArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *minPrisSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *maxPrisSlider;

-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

**SearchViewController.m:**

---

Fill allObjectsArray:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Wine.plist"];
allObjectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

---

Add or remove object from suitsArray, I have 10 buttons similar to this:

```
-(IBAction)lambButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
if (lambButtonSelected == 0) {

    lambButtonSelected = 1;
    [suitsArray addObject:@"lamb"];

} else {

    lambButtonSelected = 0;
    [suitsArray removeObject:@"lamb"];

}
}
```

---

Then, add objects to search results:

```
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{  

resultObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary *wine in allObjectsArray)

    {

    //String for price
    NSString *winePrice = [wine objectForKey:@"Price"];        

    /*THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO CHECK IF THE WORDS IN suitsCriteriaString
    ARE EXISTING IN wineSuitsString */

    NSString *suitsCriteriaString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", suitsArray];
    NSString *wineSuitsString = [wine objectForKey:@"Suits"];
    NSRange range = [wineSuitsString rangeOfString:suitsCriteriaString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];


    //THEN LAST, ADD OBJECTS WITH MATCH OF PRICE CRITERIA AND SUITS CRITERIA TO RESULTS:

    BOOL priceConditionGood = YES;
    if (minPrisSlider.value <= maxPrisSlider.value && (winePrice.floatValue < minPrisSlider.value || winePrice.floatValue > maxPrisSlider.value))
        priceConditionGood = NO;
    if (range.location != NSNotFound && priceConditionGood)
        [resultObjectsArray addObject:wine];
     }
     }

//AND PUSH RESULTS CONTROLLER:

ResultsTableViewController *nextController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultsController"];
nextController.objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:resultObjectsArray];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: PS: I'm asking for code examples, I'm not able of making a working code for this myself though I kind of understand what needs to be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"suitsCriteriaString" is not going to give you what you want. It's going to be a whole lot easier to just iterate over "suitsArray" and compare each word:

```
NSString *wineSuitsString = [wine objectForKey:@"Suits"];
BOOL foundMatch = true;
for (NSString *suit in suitsArray) {
  NSRange range = [wineSuitsString rangeOfString:suit options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
  if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    foundMatch = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you integrate this into my action so I understand how it's done? Should I delete suitsCriteriaString and put in this code instead or what? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, edited to add the "wineSuitsString = " line to the top.  You can replace your original code (the first code block you posted in your question) with this.

Comment: One issue in this line: **if ((range.location != NSNotFound && priceConditionGood))** now 'range' is undeclared identitier!

Comment: You shouldn't be using range.location at all here.  Use the value of foundMatch instead.

Comment: if ((foundMatch != false && priceConditionGood)) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the componentsJoinedByString: method like that:

```
NSString *suitsCriteriaString = [suitsArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSString *wineSuitsString = [wine objectForKey:@"Suits"];
NSRange range = [wineSuitsString rangeOfString:suitsCriteriaString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this works only when suitsArray containing 1 word, not with 2 words etc, and not if is empty (0 words). If empty, it should just skip this criteria and use only price criteria. Can you fix this too?